# What is a deterministic, non-negative, and Borel-measurable function?

Tags: measure-theory, functions

May I know the intuitive understanding of a deterministic, non-negative, and Borel-measurable function?

Especially, I am not sure what the 'deterministic' and 'Borel-measurable' functions are.

Could you please help me understand this in the most easiest way?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know what a borel space is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Borel (sub)set is a set that can be created from open sets by countable union, countable intersection and relative complement. A Borel-measurable function is one where every preimage of an interval is a borel set.

In other words if $ f : \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R} $ is a borel measurable function then for every interval $\Delta$, $f^{-1}[\Delta]$ is a borel subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Deterministic functions are functions that always give the same value for the same attributes in other words functions that are nonrandom.

Comment: Thank you so much. Then correct me if I am wrong. Can I call the function nondeterministic if it reruns 1 if x is greater than 5 and 0 otherwise? Can I assume that a function that can give identical values for a random number like this will be nondeterministic?

Comment: No that is not a nondeterministic function,  a non deterministic function would return diffrent values for the same input.

Comment: I see. So it's like using a function with random number generator?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for your confirmation.